# Decrease mistake severity for Ruff python linter in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm testing out the [Ruff](https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff) python linter's [vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charliermarsh.ruff), and can't quite figure out how to do this. Currently, any style violation i made shows up as a warning on the file. See picture below.

[image]

Essentially, I'd like to make these violation highlights less intrusive. This is odd but i have tried including `"ruff.logLevel":"debug"` in my `settings.json` but it doesn't seem to have any impact on the file. A couple of things can solve my problem.

1. A quick way to disable the highlights without disabling the Ruff extension.
2. A reduced severity level for the violations. Something similar to the `Hint` diagnostic level

Apologies if my questions isn't very clear, let me know how i can help.

Answer (score 7):

Hiding and disabling error messages is not an ideal solution. Instead, you can inform `ruff` that your project uses a different line-length parameter. To do this open or create `pyproject.toml` and add the following:

```
[tool.ruff]
line-length = 120
```

If you use autoformatter it's good to make sure that both `ruff` and it use the same line-length parameter and then you won't see these errors again.

Comment: thank you. For more info:  https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/configuration/#using-pyprojecttoml

Comment: how should I proceed if I want to set ruff formatting/linting `line-length` at the user level in vscode ? Where does the `.toml` should be put ?

Answer (score 6):

I typically use a formatter like black to handle this instead, and I don't want to bloat up my project by adding a configuration file, so I just disable it altogether by adding this to my VScode `settings.json` file:

```json
"ruff.lint.args": ["--ignore", "E501"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that no longer works. It says `Ruff: Lint failed (error: unexpected argument '--ignore E501' found ...`, It also says `Deprecated. Please use ruff.lint.args instead`. But when I change ruff.args to ruff.lint.args I get the same error, which completely disables ruff

Comment: Fixed it. It is now `"ruff.lint.args": ["--ignore=E701"]`